# Error in my matlab program to perform the for loop

Tags: matlab

To reduce the size of a program with repetitive parts, I want to make a loop. But I got the following problem:

```
 for n=1:4
    .
    .
    .

    [A,B,C,D] =  ['A002A_' num2str(n)] '_Filtre'(matrices{:});  
    .
    .
  end

??? Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

this line is to replace:

```
[A, B, C, D] = A002A_1_Filtre(matrices {:});
```

the loop is made on the position of the value 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `eval` when you want to dynamically evaluate commands in MATLAB based on creating strings.  What you're doing in the loop is that you are trying to construct a **string** and magically assigning the string to four variables `A,B,C,D`.  If you want *a command to execute*, use `eval`.  In other words, do this:

```
for n=1:4
   .
   .
   .
   [A,B,C,D] =  eval(['A002A_' num2str(n) '_Filtre(matrices{:});']);  
   .
   .
 end
```

Make sure that `eval` contains a string.  This string is essentially the command you want MATLAB to execute.

**NB:** This is *assuming* that `matrices` is already defined in your workspace prior to using this code.  As such, make sure `matrices` is declared.